# Is there a way to "set *" on a Spark/Databricks merge query when all columns are not in the source?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I'm merging data from one table into another in Spark/Databricks.  I can do and `update set *` if all columns are selected but this fails if all columns are not selected (e.g. if there is a col9 in the dst table in the query below).  Is there a way to do this merge without repeating the long list of columns in the `when matched` (i.e. match by column name in the source query) and `when not matched` segments?

```
merge into demo dst
using (
select distinct
  col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  col4,
  col5,
  col6,
  col7,
  col8
from
  demo_raw
where 1=1
  and col1 = 'ac'
  and col2 is not null
) src
on src.col1 = dst.col1
when matched then
  update set *
when not matched then
  insert *
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a python solution that I'm somewhat content with:

**Function Definition:**

```
%python
def merge(srcTableName, dstTableName, whereStr, joinStr, cols, selectCols, debug):
  
  # create the sql string
  sqlString = ""
  sqlString += "merge into " + dstTableName + " t\n"
  sqlString += "using ( \n"
  sqlString += "select \n"
  for str in selectCols[:-1]:
    sqlString += "  " + str + ", \n"
  sqlString += "  " + selectCols[-1] + "\n"
  sqlString += "from " + srcTableName
  sqlString += whereStr + "\n"
  sqlString += ") s\n"
  sqlString += "on \n"
  sqlString += joinStr + "\n"
  sqlString += "when matched then update set \n"
  updateCols = [s + " = s." + s for s in cols]
  for str in updateCols[:-1]:
    sqlString += "  " + str + ", \n"
  sqlString += "  " + updateCols[-1]
  sqlString += """
  when not matched then 
  insert (
  """
  for str in cols[:-1]:
    sqlString += "  " + str + ", \n"
  sqlString += "  " + cols[-1]
  sqlString += """
  )
  values (
  """
  for str in cols[:-1]:
    sqlString += "  " + str + ", \n"
  sqlString += "  " + cols[-1] + "\n"
  sqlString += ")"

  if debug == True:
    print(sqlString)

  spark.sql(sqlString)
  return sqlString
```

**Example Call:**

```
# define the tables (FROM MY_PROJECT.DEMO TO DEMO)
srcTableName = "my_project.demo"
dstTableName = "demo"
# define the where clause (ONLY AC DATA)
whereStr = """
where 1=1
  and org = 'ac'
  and org_patient_id is not null
"""
# define the join (MATCH ON PATIENT_ID)
joinStr = "t.patient_id = s.patient_id"
# define the columns (JUST THESE COLUMNS)
cols = [
  'org',
  'data_lot',
  'raw_table',
  'org_patient_id',
  'patient_id',
  'sex',
  'sexual_orientation',
  'year_of_birth',
  'year_of_death',
  'race',
  'ethnicity',
  'city',
  'state',
  'zip'  
]
# create any needed aliases for query string
selectCols = cols
selectCols = [x if x != 'year_of_birth' else '(2020 - age) as year_of_birth' for x in selectCols]
# do the merge
merge(srcTableName, dstTableName, whereStr, joinStr, cols, selectCols)
print("Done.")
```

Answer (score 1):

MERGE INTO target
USING source
ON source.key = target.key
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT *
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/merge